# Start another background activity from background activity

Tags: android

Is it possible to start setvices from services ? So my program function is whenever the AlarmManager triggering, it will start another activity but still in the background proccess. So the user wouldn't notice about any activity has started.

Is there any reference ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a thread that is executed for your alarm manager function, and whenever the condition is met in your alarm manager function that requires the launch of another service, execute another thread.